# Active Directory group member role check

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to determine if a login has a specific role attached to it using the `IS_SRVROLEMEMBER` query, however the login I am trying to determine if he has a role is part of an AD group which is attached to the role.

If I do the query

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', 'Domain\User')
```

I get back `NULL`

If I do the same query on a different server that just has that login attached to the role instead of an entire group I get back `1` as expected.

Would I connect with that particular login to the SQL Server and execute

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin')
```

I get back `1` on both servers

How do I go about checking if a login has access to a role when a group it belongs to has been attached to that role instead of a specific login?

Comment: On the server returning NULL, does `SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals` show the login you're trying to test?

Comment: Also, a side note about terminology:  At the server level, principals are known as "logins".  At the database level, principals are known as "users".  Logins are mapped to users.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll edit it in a moment then to reflect the proper terminology. But to answer your question: that query returns me the AD group name that the login is part of, but not the login itself

Comment: You mean the individual AD user accounts aren't SQL Server logins?  Only the group is?  Yeah, that's not going to work.  Maybe you should try [xp_logininfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190369.aspx)? You could use `EXEC xp_logininfo 'Domain\GroupName', 'members'` to get a list of AD user accounts that are associated with the login group.

Comment: That would work, except the tool I am building is meant for more than just our own company, so all I got to go on is the login. I don't 'know' the group name, so while I can query that and see my login name in that list that I want to check it is not a solution to the problem sadly

Comment: However, looking through what xp_logininfo has to offer I might have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Using xp_logininfo suggested by [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) I have a solution that appears to work for my needs. I am not sure of any implications just yet but the results so far look good.

EDIT: If two (or more for that matter) groups were added that both had the user, the script failed. So rewrote it a little, resulting in completely ignoring the `IS_SRVROLEMEMBER` now and just doing the checking myself. This works with multiple groups. Returns the same result as the `IS_SRVROLEMEMBER` function, NULL when no permission to check for roles and either 1 or 0 if the role check succeeds or not.

```
declare @result int

create table #temp (
    [account name] nvarchar(40),
    [type] nvarchar(40),
    [privilege] nvarchar(40),
    [mapped login name] nvarchar(40),
    [permission path] nvarchar(40))
begin try
    insert into #temp exec xp_logininfo 'Domain\User', 'all' 
    if exists (select * from sys.server_role_members as RM
        inner join sys.server_principals as R on R.principal_id = RM.role_principal_id
        inner join sys.server_principals as L on L.principal_id = RM.member_principal_id
        inner join #temp as T on L.name = T.[permission path] or L.name = T.[mapped login name]
        where R.name = 'sysadmin')
        set @result = 1
    else
        set @result = 0;
end try     
begin catch
    set @result = -1 -- Current login is not a sysadmin, nothing to worry about
end catch               

select case @result when -1 then NULL when 0 then 0 when 1 then 1 end
drop table #temp
```